Automatically add parentheses when calling a JavaScript method in VS Code
In my vs code I want to put some configuration or extension so that when I call a method it automatically puts parentheses without me having to type the parentheses
like when I call any string function or console.log it never gives the option to complete with parentheses like this -------> console.log('asasasasas')

How do you expect it to know it's a function call if there are no parenthesis yet?

Or...just type the two characters? There is no automated tool that will correctly do it for you in all cases. Consider somePromise.then(console.log) which is the correct code. somePromise.then(console.log()) is not. Most editors have an option to complete the paired elements (brackets, quotes, etc. that go in pairs) for you automatically, thus cutting your effort by 50% anyway.
